Can support of finitely generated module be complement of single point?
As we know from Stacks Project:10.78 Finite projective modules, a finitely generated module is locally free of finite rank iff it is projective.
From (proof of) Hartshorne Exercise 2.5.7(a), if a finitely generated module over a Noetherian ring is free at some prime ideal, then it is locally free at the prime ideal.
Without the assumption of Noetherian, the original proof no more holds. I think we can find example to this, or equivalently to ask

Can we find a commutative ring (which must be non-Noetherian) $R$, a finitely generated module $M$ over $R$, and $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathrm{Spec} (R)$, such that  $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a free $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ module, which is to say $M$ is free at $\mathfrak{p}$, but not at all (or any) points near $\mathfrak{p}$.

If we want for any prime except $\mathfrak{p}$, by reducing to some principal open it is equivalent to

Can we find a commutative ring (which must be non-Noetherian) $R$, a finitely generated module $M$ over $R$, and $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathrm{Spec} (R)$, such that  $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a free $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ module, which is to say $M$ is free at $\mathfrak{p}$, but not at any points except $\mathfrak{p}$. 
(Or to say, $M_f$ is not a free $R_f$ module for $f$ not in $\mathfrak{p}$.)

There are examples with $M$ not finitely generated in example-of-a-module-which-is-free-at-an-isolated-point.
My question is: Without an assumption of Noetherian, does (it seems not) Hartshorne's Exercise 2.5.7(a) (which is to say for finitely generated module, pointwise freeness implies local freeness) hold?

There is a question proposed in the title but not in the setup. This seems ill-formed.

My main question is without assumption of Noetherian, does (it seems not) Hartshorne Exercise 2.5.7(a) (which is to say for finitely generated module, pointwise freeness implies local freeness) hold?

You misunderstood something, Noetherian is not relevant here.
You can consider the $R \times S$-module $M \times N$ for an $R$-module $M$ and an $S$-module $N$. Let $R,S$ be Artinian local, and take $M$ to be a free module and $N$ be any non-free module. Both can be finitely generated. The spectrum then has two points, and the localization of $M \times N$ at the first point is $M$, and the other one is $N$.

Could you explain that in more details?

But, in this example there is still an open neighbourhood $U$ of $\mathfrak p$ (namely ${\mathfrak p}$) on which the module is free?
